# unable to fetch data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have table where the patient test is stored and in another table the report result is saved by test_id defined in test table, now the test id is fixed and and i am fetching report result by the test_id but one can be more time by any user so the report resullt is updating in table but when i am trying to make report the old one report result is fetching, so, is there any solution for display only current result when the test_id is same in the table, this is my table image [image]

i want to try fetch current result but it showing previous result.and here is code

```
 function get_test_report( $test_id )
        {
            gri("report", "WHERE rep_te_id = '$test_id'", "", $report);


            if($lab[lab_test_rl_id] == 4)                       # lab report
            {
                return get_lab_content( $report[rep_result], $lab[id] );
            }
            else                                                # other report
            {
                return $report[rep_result];
            }
        }
```

hope you will understand becouse my english is not well, any idea will be very much appreciated

Comment: Do you want to get the row with the highest `rep_date` for the test id?

Comment: i think you need a "ORDER BY rep_date DESC LIMIT 1" at the end of your query. This will get you only the newest line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM report
WHERE rep_te_id = '$test_id'
ORDER by rep_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

In your PHP, you're not using the proper syntax to access associative array elements. You need to quote the keys, so it should be `$report['rep_result']` (the exception to this is when you're interpolating in a string, then you must leave the quotes out unless you wrap it with `{}`).

Comment: You didn't describe the problem clearly, so I was just guessing this would be the fix (ITroubs guessed the same thing). Please edit your question and clarify it.